# Git merge not appearing on remote repository without push

Tags: git, merge, repository

This is a newbie Git question, but I haven't found an answer on Stack Overflow that could make it clear to me.

Basically, I was working on a branch on my computer:

```
$ git checkout -b my_branch
```

Then, I made a few changes in my files. Afterwards, inside `my_branch`, I added, committed, and pushed the files I edited.

But then, I decided that I wanted to put those changes (the ones on `my_branch`) on `master`. And here comes the problem.
I did:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge my_branch
```

Everything was ok on my local repository. But when I went to the website where I can see my remote repository, my merge was not there.
So, I decided to do a simple

```
$ git push
```

without any changes to my files.

It worked. So, is executing an "empty" push the only way to see my local merge on the remote repository?

Comment: What do you mean by empty push? You would’ve pushed the merge

Comment: Oh, I'm used to do a "git push" only when I've edited code on my files, that's why I was saying I did an "empty push", because nothing really changed, only the merge. So I suppose I can do a push without having edited any files, and that's why the merge appeared on the remote after that command, right?

Comment: The change was the merge. You can push whenever, but it won’t do anything if there’s nothing to push.

Answer (score 2):

Your Git repository is local. The remote repository is simply another copy of it. When you add a commit, either by changing something and running `git commit`, or by merging something using `git merge`, this happens locally. Nothing is sent over the network.

The only time data is sent over the network is when you explicitly run a command like `git push`, `git fetch`, `git pull`.

A merge commit is similar to any other commit. It is simply the result of combining the state of one line of history with another. So even though you did not edit any files, the merge commit will typically have caused changes to files.

If there is a commit, it can be pushed or fetched. The kind of commit is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

You can see if you have changes to do with "git status". When you did the merge of my_branch with master you didn't made any change in the code... just the merge.

Also if you want to be sure you have made all the changes to your online repository you can make git push --all and of course, as i said before, check them with git status.

Comment: > "The merges makes their commit automatically and don't need to be pushed."

No, merges are not automatically pushed.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple that when you create branches on your local computer, those branches are on local computer only, not on your remote repo(i.e. Github profile)

So what you need to do is, push it in your Github repo.

for example,

**1.you created branch:**

```
git checkout <BRANCH_NAME>
```

**2. you merged it using(to accomplish merge, you must be on your master or where you want to merge that branch),**

```
git merge <BRANCH_NAME>
```

**3. Now you need to push it to the remote Github repo using following,**

```
git push
```

Hopefully, now its clear.

credit: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials